# Ограничить срабатывание события в родительском DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть 2 **DataGrid** . И 1 вложенный во второй. Оба имеют событие `MouseLeftButtonUp="dgCompletedJobsMouseUp"`. Во внешнем гриде работает так как надо. Но когда кликаешь по внутреннему DataGrid, то событие срабатывает дважды. Для родительского и для дочернего DataGrid. Если увеличить вложенность то и событие будет обрабатываться больше раз. Как можно это контролировать?

Обработчик события:

```
private void dgCompletedJobsMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            HeaderViewModel viewModel = (HeaderViewModel)DataContext;
            if (viewModel.RowDetailsVisible == DataGridRowDetailsVisibilityMode.Collapsed)
            {
                viewModel.RowDetailsVisible = DataGridRowDetailsVisibilityMode.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                viewModel.RowDetailsVisible = DataGridRowDetailsVisibilityMode.Collapsed;
            }
        }
```

Код во ViewModel:

```
private DataGridRowDetailsVisibilityMode _rowDetailsVisible;
public DataGridRowDetailsVisibilityMode RowDetailsVisible { get => _rowDetailsVisible; set { _rowDetailsVisible = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
```

Xaml:

````
<DataGrid Name="DataGrid1"  ItemsSource="{Binding Chapters, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
                       RowDetailsVisibilityMode="{Binding RowDetailsVisible}" MouseLeftButtonUp="dgCompletedJobsMouseUp"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,0,0,0" CanUserAddRows="False" Focusable="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Command="{Binding AddHeader, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">+</Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="16" x:Name="Column1" FontWeight="Bold" Width="10*" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="14" x:Name="Column2" FontWeight="Bold" Width="2*" Header="Unit"              />
                    <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="14" x:Name="Column3" FontWeight="Bold" Width="3*" Header="Quantity"          />
                    <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="14" x:Name="Column4" FontWeight="Bold" Width="4*" Header="WorkUnitCost"      />
                    <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="14" x:Name="Column5" FontWeight="Bold" Width="4*" Header="WorkTotalCost"     />
                    <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="14" x:Name="Column6" FontWeight="Bold" Width="4*" Header="MaterialUnitCost"  />
                    <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="14" x:Name="Column7" FontWeight="Bold" Width="4*" Header="MaterialTotalCost" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="14" x:Name="Column8" FontWeight="Bold" Width="4*" Header="TotalCostUAN"      Binding="{Binding TotalCost, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="14" x:Name="Column9" FontWeight="Bold" Width="4*" Header="TotalCostUSD"      />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Headers}"
                          RowDetailsVisibilityMode="{Binding RowDetailsVisible}" MouseLeftButtonUp="dgCompletedJobsMouseUp"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" HeadersVisibility="None"  Focusable="True"
                          Margin="14,0,0,0">
                            <DataGrid.Columns >
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Button Command="{Binding AddWork, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">+</Button>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Width="{Binding Source={x:Reference Column1},Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource differenceConvertor}, ConverterParameter=15}" Header="Name"              Binding="{Binding Name}" >
                                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                        <Style>
                                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                </DataGridTextColumn>
                                <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Width="{Binding Source={x:Reference Column2},Path=ActualWidth}" Binding="{Binding CountWork.Unit, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Width="{Binding Source={x:Reference Column3},Path=ActualWidth}" Binding="{Binding CountWork.Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Width="{Binding Source={x:Reference Column4},Path=ActualWidth}" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Width="{Binding Source={x:Reference Column5},Path=ActualWidth}" Binding="{Binding TotalWorkCost, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Width="{Binding Source={x:Reference Column6},Path=ActualWidth}" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Width="{Binding Source={x:Reference Column7},Path=ActualWidth}" Binding="{Binding TotalMaterialCost, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Width="{Binding Source={x:Reference Column8},Path=ActualWidth}" Binding="{Binding TotalCost, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Width="{Binding Source={x:Reference Column9},Path=ActualWidth}" />
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                           
                        </DataGrid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

            </DataGrid>```
````

Comment: Что значит контролировать? Вы хотите узнать инициатора события или хотите чтобы один раз возникало событие?

Comment: @Cruz21 Просто получается что инициатором событий становятся сразу все гриды. А мне надо чтоб родительский Грид не реагировал на клики по дочерних элементах. При этом событие сначало срабатывает во внешнем гриде, а потом во вложеном.

Comment: используйте маршрутизацию событий.
подробнее можете посмотреть тут: 
https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/6.php